# Cannot get NSURLConnection, but app keeps waiting

Tags: ios, ios4, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

So i have an app that connects to an internal IP Address. So i want to implement code that will make sure the NSSURLConnections is made (i.e. connected to the wireless network) because i wont be able to connect to the server if i am not on the wireless network. The problem is before i can check it goes and gets stuck. I implemented

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
```

but it never gets called. Any ideas on how to proceed?

this is my code to create the connection

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.192.4/file.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

after this last line, it goes off in the wild blue yonder!

***UPDATE**********

this is the method that is called when a button is pressed.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.192.4/file.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[request release];
[connection release];
```

i also implemented these methods:

didFailWithError:(NSError *)

didFinishLoading

didRecieveData

I just changed the connection to (nonatomic, retain) ...there was no autocomplete option for strong. any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case you are not using ARC but you have a similar issue. you are releasing `connection` right after you alloc/init it so the connection is never starting. Remove `[connection release]` and release it via the property in the two delegate methods for connection completion as I note below.

FOR REFERENCE:
if your project is using ARC, `connection` will be released right after the run loop ends as nothing is retaining it. Try creating a (nonatomic, strong) property to retain the connection. Nil the property when the connection has completed.

in MyClass.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSURLConnection * connection;
```

in MyClass.m

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize connection;

- (void)requestData
{
    // create request

    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:...];

    // in connection delegate method for successful completion or error set self.connection = nil;
}
```

EDIT: clarified ARC info

EDIT #2: added non-arc answer at top

Comment: Good catch with ARC, that sounds quite probable. I think you can safely rewrite the answer to include the ARC part only.

Comment: @XJones if i am not declaring my connection variable in the .H file, how would i add the (nonatomic, strong) to it? maybe just declare it there?

Comment: @XJones i just did that, but i had no option for strong

Comment: well, my answer only is relevant if you are using ARC? are you? strong is a valid property option in XCode 4.2. If you are using an earlier version of xcode than you can't being using ARC and strong won't be available.

Comment: actually, looks like you are not using ARC as you wouldn't be releasing your objects. that's disallowed with ARC.

Comment: @XJones i am going to update to 4.2, i just realized that was the disconnect

Comment: I see your problem. You are initializing the connection and then immediately releasing it. therefore it never starts. take out `[connection release]` and release the `connection` property when the request is finished in each of the delegate methods. While you are not using ARC, you have the same problem as I mentionned. The connection is released before it begins.

Answer (score 0):

Is the returned connection non-nil? Are you doing this on the main thread or a thread equipped with a run loop?

Comment: i am not getting anything returned or atleast i dont think i am. Yes this is on the main thread

Comment: If you are not getting the connection back, try a synchronous connection and pass the `error` argument to see what’s wrong.